# How can I deploy fields on the new ServiceAppointment or ServiceTerritory objects?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, field-service-lightning

Salesforce has baked some standard Field Service Lightning objects into the Winter 17 release, like "ServiceAppointment". But those do not appear to be exposed in the metadata API or in ChangeSets. How can we deploy these?

Answer (score 0):

The key to being able to download and deploy these is to have the appropriate FSL permission set licenses and permissions sets on the user you're using to perform the action. In that respect, it's like CampaignInfluence and some other features that are not even accessible via the API unless the accessing user has the appropriate permission set licenses. FSL objects include:

- OperatingHours
- ServiceAppointment
- ServiceResource
- ServiceResourceSkill
- ServiceTerritory
- ServiceTerritoryMember

If your user account in the **source** org does not have FSL permissions you won't be able to see/download this metadata. If your user account in the **destination** org doesn't have FSL permissions you will receive an error like:

> The object "ServiceAppointment" can't be updated through a flow.